# Port from XCode (MAC) to Windows and Linux

Tags: xcode, unix, portability

I have a project developed on XCode IDE (running on OSX) and I want to be able to run this program on linux and windows environments, i.e. create a makefile for this project. Would someone describe the steps to I can do this?

Comment: In short the answer is you cannot do this. There are many differences in the compilers and available frameworks. See here for more details: https://superuser.com/questions/12719/any-way-to-run-mac-osx-software-under-windows

Comment: Hi Russel. Excluding the portability to Windows, could I port the MAC code to another unix based system, like ubuntu? I'd never created a Makefile, only compiled it, so I don't have much idea how can I proceed. Thanks.

Comment: Here's the answer to your question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/6229/can-i-run-osx-applications

Comment: I think you may also benefit from understanding the differences between OSX and Ubuntu: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4091/is-linux-a-unix

Comment: Hey man, thanks again. I'm reading the material. But It seems like in each of those posts that you listed people are trying to port the binary. In my case, I wrote the entire code, so the source-code is here. I'm actually trying to generate the binary to other plataforms (Linux and Windows). It don't change anything? (maybe I have expressed myself bad, english is not my first language as you maybe has noticed).

Comment: Gotcha. In order to compile the source code on another platform you will need access to a cross-platform objective-c or swift compiler with compatible libraries. Without the appropriate tools and compilers, there is no way to generate the binaries from source code. I've never used this, but it may be of help: http://www.cocotron.org/ - Cocotron is a developer SDK which implements a usable amount AppKit and Foundation for Windows and Foundation for Linux/BSD in Objective-C